# Open Page do Actions Silently

Tags: c#, c++

How would I make a program connect to a webpage SILENTLY and do certain actions silently?

Example:
1. connects to google
2. searches (input)
3. click "I'm feelings lucky"

Comment: What you're talking about is web scraping and javascript injection. Google it, grab some code, play with it, and if you get stuck on something specific, share your code and your problem/error specifically, and we'll be glad to help. Please try searching for solutions using Google and SO searches first, though.

Comment: I didn't even know what to google ;/

Comment: https://www.google.com/#q=c-sharp+web+scraping and https://www.google.com/#q=c-sharp+javascript+injection Good luck!

Comment: Just unplug the speakers.  It will all be silent then.

Answer (score 0):

Read about Web Scraping here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_scraping and understand the concepts and then try to play with some code. You will probably need some JavaScript knowledge also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript.

Hopefully that will help.